# Get data from ajax request to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

I have 2 requests

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://sandbox.gasvisor.com:9988/uaa/oauth/token",
    data: "grant_type=client_credentials",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization':'Basic SVRXRV9XRUJfQVBQOml0d2VfY2xpZW50' },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        getData(data.access_token);
    }
})

function getData(acess_token){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://sandbox.gasvisor.com/api/v2/gobjects/search/withinRadius?longitude=24.711117&latitude=48.922633&radius=10",
        headers: { 
            'Authorization':'bearer'+acess_token },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        })    
}
```

They return json from server. I need to get data from Json file to my Angular listing. Pls help me.

Comment: Use Angular way to do Ajax with $http, please add Angular relevant code.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with $http. I need to get data from Json and post it in Angular with ng-repeat. I know how to use ng-repeat, but can't find how to do my request with $http

Comment: Use this link and see what you can learn: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example for one of your call:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://sandbox.gasvisor.com:9988/uaa/oauth/token',
  data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization':'Basic SVRXRV9XRUJfQVBQOml0d2VfY2xpZW50' },
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    $scope.response = response;
  }, function errorCallback(err) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    $scope.error = err;
});
```